# Testing event submission into a service

Tags: scala, testing, mockito, scalatest

I'm testing a service implementation which performs some asynchronous computation. Here is the trait

```
trait Event
trait Service{
    def processEvents(ex: Seq[Event])
}
```

I have the following implementation:

```
//Business logic
trait EventHandler{
     def handleEvent(e: Event)
}

//Threading
class AsynchronousService(private final val handler: EventHandler)
     extends Service {
     def processEvents(ex: Seq[Event]) = {
        //execute handler.handleEvent(e) in some 
        //thread pool or so...
        //should not do any processing in case of ex.isEmpty
     }
}
```

The problem I encountered is when testing the `AsynchronousService` for empty `Seq[Event]`. Here is my test in scalatest:

```
it("should verify no processing in case of empty event seq"){
    val mockedHandler = //mock with Mockito
    val service = new AsynchronousService(mockedHandler)
    service.processEvents(Seq())
    Thread.sleep(1000) //<--- waiting some time. looks ugly
    verifyZeroInteraction(mockedHandler)
}
```

The problem is with `Thread.sleep(1000)`. As long as the `AsynchronousService` perform scheduling/submission/or something else to another thread it would be incorrect to conclude without waiting some time and then perform `verifyZeroInteraction(mockedHandler)`. But `Thread.sleep(1000)` looks weird.

***QUESTION***: Is there `Scalatest` facility for that maybe? Or how to write such a test correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ScalaFutures`

`import org.scalatest.concurrent.ScalaFutures`

For example:

```
 val futEvents: Future[???] = service.processEvents(Seq())

 whenReady(futEvents, testTimeout) { events =>
    // do your testing
    verifyZeroInteraction(mockedHandler)
  }
```

This expects of course that `service.processEvents(Seq())` returns a Future!

Here is a nice Blog that describes that and other possibilities: [testing-future-objects-scalatest](https://lucianomolinari.com/2016/08/07/testing-future-objects-scalatest/)

Comment: Thanks. But can we do something more pretty than `Thread.sleep` in case "fire-and-forget" without returning future?

Comment: You don't need `Thread.sleep` at all! as long you stay in the whenReady clause. I added your tests in my answer

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is to pass the ThreadPool/Executor/Whatever as a dependency, then you can stub/mock it and so it would execute synchronously, so your test is much better

```
//Business logic
trait EventHandler{
  def handleEvent(e: Event)
}

//Threading
class AsynchronousService(handler: EventHandler, executor: Executor)
  extends Service {
  def processEvents(ex: Seq[Event]) = {
    executor.execute(handler.handleEvent(<blah>))
  }
}
```

and then the test

```
it("should verify no processing in case of empty event seq"){
  val mockedHandler = //mock with Mockito
  val mockExecutor = //mock with Mockito
  when(mockExecutor.execute(any)) thenAnswer { invocation =>
    val codeBlock: () => Unit = invocation.getArgument(0)
    codeBlock()
  }
  val service = new AsynchronousService(mockedHandler, mockExecutor)
  service.processEvents(Seq())
  verifyZeroInteraction(mockedHandler)
}
```

Of course I'm making-up the class Executor, you should adapt your code to use whatever you're using, but that's the idea.
You could also use a stub instead of a mock for the Executor, but depending on what you're using a mock maybe easier, that code assumes Scala 2.12 BTW, otherwise the syntax for the thenAnswer is different

Hope it helps